# XML not formatting correctly

Tags: xml

I'm quite new to xml coding and maybe thinking I bit off more than I can chew. I can get them to run fine alone separately but when I try and combine the it does not work or the formating is bad. trying to incorporate this java process to incorporate single quotes to a file name here is the process name to add the single quote. I need the concat to happen first with file name and unique identifier and then I need to take that filename and add the single quotes basically.
`

```
            <!-- <assign to="DestinationMessageName" from="concat(DestinationMessageName,'.T',string(mfExtension))" /> -->

            <assign to="NewFilename"  from="
                if(string-length(NewFilename) &gt; 0, 
                    concat(NewFilename, '.T',string(mfExtension)),
                    if(string-length(C_RENAME_MASK) &gt; 0, 
                        concat(C_RENAME_MASK, '.T',string(mfExtension )),
                        concat(DestinationMessageName, '.T',string(mfExtension))
                       )
                    )" 
            />

        </output>
        <input message="inmsg">  
            <assign to="." from="*"></assign>
        </input>    
    </operation>
</sequence>
```

`

Here is the original process where it concats the filename and a unique indentifier at the end of a file name. example filename.T123456
I still need the filename and unique indentifier but I need to encompass the whole thing in single quotes. 'filename.T123456'

```
    <process name="test_quote_JavaTask">
 <sequence>
    <assign to="NewFilename">"*"</assign>
    <operation name="JavaTask Service">
      <participant name="Quote_Java_task"/>
      <output message="JavaTaskInputMessage">
        <assign to="." from="*"></assign>
      </output>
      <input message="inmsg">
        <assign to="." from="*"></assign>
      </input>
    </operation>
  </sequence>
</process>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.